# Blender - артефакты. Появляются темные области на сторонах объекта

Tags: 3d, blender

Появляются такие артефакты(черные области). Две вершины на одних координатах точно отсутствуют. Подскажите советом как решить эту проблему.

Модификаторов на объекте нет.

Программа: Blender 3d 3.1.0

[image: Темные артефакты]

Answer (score 0):

Не нашёл ничего лучше чем сделать так:
Выбрать нормаль, где есть артефакт -> сделать Fill -> Удалить нормаль с ошибкой (Delete faces) -> Выбрать новые нормали -> объединить новые нормали (Dessolve faces).

Способ костыль, но работает.

[image: Пример действий]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, проблема в кастомных нормалях. Нажмите кнопку "Clear custom split normals data"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы бы хоть словами написали, как выглядит «та самая кнопка, которую надо нажать».

Comment: Clear custom split normals data